# Showing Profiling Summary Report data in the frontend

Tags: devmode, debugging, logging

I'm trying to debug why certain pages on a site are slow using the 'Profiling Summary Report' data that is logged to the console when devMode is enabled.

For easy viewing, I've tried to output the values in a flash message on the front end of the site using the following code, placed in the `init()` function of a plugin:

```
if ( craft()->config->get( 'devMode' ) && craft()->request->isSiteRequest() )
{
  $debugInfo = 'Time: ' . sprintf( '%0.5f', Craft::getLogger()->getExecutionTime() ) . 's' . "\n";
  $debugInfo .= ' — ' . 'Memory: ' . number_format( Craft::getLogger()->getMemoryUsage() / 1024 ) . 'Kb';
  $debugInfo .= ' — ' . 'Queries: ' . count( Craft::getLogger()->getLogs( '', 'system.db.CDbCommand' ) );
  craft()->userSession->setFlash( 'debug', $debugInfo );
}
```

They successfully log values (that look correct for seconds, kb's and query counts) but they are different to what is displayed in the console.

**Update**: These are the values from 4 different page loads. I have a suspicion that these are referring to a different process, not the current page, as they're too consistent.

```
Time: 0.14093s — Memory: 12,458Kb — Queries: 5
Time: 0.14069s — Memory: 12,217Kb — Queries: 5
Time: 0.13179s — Memory: 12,218Kb — Queries: 5
Time: 0.13125s — Memory: 12,218Kb — Queries: 5
```

Does anybody know why this might be? I had a feeling it was logging the values of a different process to the console. Is `getLogger()` relative to where it's called?

Comment: How are you retrieving the flash data on the front-end?  My first guess is that the data you're flashing on the front-end is info for the _previous_ request, whereas what's displayed in the browser console is info for the _current_ request.

Comment: I'm using a simple `{{ craft.session.getFlash('debug') }}` currently. I'll update my question with some more info on the values.

Comment: I think your conclusion is right, I'm just not 100% sure why... `getLogger()` is relative to the current request, so if you call it over an AJAX request, it will return a new instance with different logging info.